# Importing from the 'elasticsearch.client' module is deprecated. Instead use 'elasticsearch' module for importing the client

Tags: python, elasticsearch

What is the properly way to import `IngestClient` from elasticsearch API in Python? The following, gives me the deprecated message:

> "Importing from the 'elasticsearch.client' module is deprecated. Instead use 'elasticsearch' module for importing the client."

```
from elasticsearch.client import IngestClient
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of importing `IngestClient` and then instantiating it, you can use it directly through the `Elasticsearch` instance.

For example:

```py
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch(**config)
es.ingest.get_pipeline(**options)
```

You can examine the `Elasticsearch` class if you are unsure what the instances are called.

```py
class Elasticsearch(BaseClient):
    ...
    # namespaced clients for compatibility with API names
    self.async_search = AsyncSearchClient(self)
    self.autoscaling = AutoscalingClient(self)
    self.cat = CatClient(self)
    self.cluster = ClusterClient(self)
    self.fleet = FleetClient(self)
    self.features = FeaturesClient(self)
    self.indices = IndicesClient(self)
    self.ingest = IngestClient(self)
    self.nodes = NodesClient(self)
    self.snapshot = SnapshotClient(self)
    self.tasks = TasksClient(self)

    self.xpack = XPackClient(self)
    self.ccr = CcrClient(self)
    self.dangling_indices = DanglingIndicesClient(self)
    self.enrich = EnrichClient(self)
    self.eql = EqlClient(self)
    self.graph = GraphClient(self)
    self.ilm = IlmClient(self)
    self.license = LicenseClient(self)
    self.logstash = LogstashClient(self)
    self.migration = MigrationClient(self)
    self.ml = MlClient(self)
    self.monitoring = MonitoringClient(self)
    self.rollup = RollupClient(self)
    self.search_application = SearchApplicationClient(self)
    self.searchable_snapshots = SearchableSnapshotsClient(self)
    self.security = SecurityClient(self)
    self.slm = SlmClient(self)
    self.shutdown = ShutdownClient(self)
    self.sql = SqlClient(self)
    self.ssl = SslClient(self)
    self.text_structure = TextStructureClient(self)
    self.transform = TransformClient(self)
    self.watcher = WatcherClient(self)
```